# Convert the nested dictionary to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dict:

```
{
    datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 27, 4, 10, 15, 180064, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc): {
        "$USD": "158.1727087865",
        "Apple": "3",
        "MSFT": "3",
    }
}
```

I want to transform this to a Pandas DataFrame with as index the `datetime` and in the column `'holdings'` I want the value of the pair (also a dict).

When I try to do this with following command:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        holdings_dict, orient="index", columns=["holdings"]
    )
```

I get an empty `DataFrame` and I do not know why. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: I updated my answer to better fit your question. I didn't say that you wanted to have all data in one column instead of having several columns for each brand. Though, if you wish to do simplify calculations on your dataframe after, and if for each brand where different times have different brands, you should not put them inside a "holding" column. Not doing so, the missing values will just be NaNs (i tested it) wich IMHO is much easier working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using `orient = "index"` without specifying columns works just fine for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

holdings_dict = {
    datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 27, 4, 10, 15, 180064, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc): {
        "$USD": "158.1727087865",
        "Apple": "3",
        "MSFT": "3",
    }
}

result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        holdings_dict, orient = "index"
    )
```

result :

```
                                  $USD               Apple  MSFT
2021-08-27 04:10:15.180064+00:00  158.1727087865     3      3
```

But, if you prefer your N colums, $USD and N other companies under a single columns "holdings, you can do this before doing pd.DataFrame.from_dict :

```
holdings_dict = { key  : {"holdings" : holdings_dict[key]} for key in holdings_dict.keys()}
```

wich will convert your dictionnary as you whished to create a dataframe with a column "holdings" containing a dictionnary